# Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Sales::escapeHtmlWithLinks()

Tags: magento-1.7

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Sales::escapeHtmlWithLinks() in
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mageworx/ordersedit/sales-order-view.phtml
>   on line 78

Line 78:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml/sales')->htmlEscapeWithLinks($_historyItem->getComment(), array['b','br','strong','i','u', 'a']); ?>
```

Is this related with **SUPEE-7405**? I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.
This error is related to customer frontend when attaching documents to order.
http://prntscr.com/n6wvmk

Answer (score 0):

**htmlEscapeWithLinks()** doesn't exist in **Mage\Adminhtml\Helper\Sales.php**. I can find this method there **escapeHtmlWithLinks()**. Try replacing this and see if what happens. The patch does few changes but the method remains unaltered. So try replacing the method name and see what happens.

These are the changes the patch does

```
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
index 72c43a8..da9af0f 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
@@ -120,19 +120,38 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Sales extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
      */
     public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
     {
-        if (is_string($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
-            $links = array();
+        if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
+            $links = [];
             $i = 1;
             $data = str_replace('%', '%%', $data);
-            $regexp = '@(<a[^>]*>(?:[^<]|<[^/]|</[^a]|</a[^>])*</a>)@';
+            $regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href\s*?=\s*?([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
             while (preg_match($regexp, $data, $matches)) {
-                $links[] = $matches[1];
-                $data = str_replace($matches[1], '%' . $i . '$s', $data);
+                //Revert the sprintf escaping
+                $url = str_replace('%%', '%', $matches[2]);
+                $text = str_replace('%%', '%', $matches[3]);
+                //Check for an valid url
+                if ($url) {
+                    $urlScheme = strtolower(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
+                    if ($urlScheme !== 'http' && $urlScheme !== 'https') {
+                        $url = null;
+                    }
+                }
+                //Use hash tag as fallback
+                if (!$url) {
+                    $url = '#';
+                }
+                //Recreate a minimalistic secure a tag
+                $links[] = sprintf(
+                    '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
+                    htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false),
+                    parent::escapeHtml($text)
+                );
+                $data = str_replace($matches[0], '%' . $i . '$s', $data);
                 ++$i;
             }
-            $data = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
+            $data = parent::escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
             return vsprintf($data, $links);
         }
-        return Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
+        return parent::escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
     }
-}
```